# Compilation Error due to InCorrect Direct X Version

Tags: c++, winapi, sdk, directx

I got the Sample Project for video capture from video Camera. I was trying to compiling it.
I am Using windows 7 and vs 2008.

I got following compilation error.

1>------ Build started: Project: VidCap, Configuration: Debug Unicode Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'Wp64' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
1>VidCap.cpp

1>c:\vikram\0.3.0.810\sdk\windows\x86\webcamsdk\samples\windows\libwebcamsrc\stream.h(20) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'streams.h': No such file or directory

1>Project : warning PRJ0018 : The following environment variables were not found:
1>$(COMMONLIB)

**Additional Include Directory :**
....\Include;"$(COMMONLIB)\DX9SDK_updated\Classes";"$(COMMONLIB)\DX9SDK_updated\include"

My assumption is it is due to DirectX Sdk So I have downloaded dxsdk_oct2005 from msdn.

But after installation I am can't see  those path in my System.

Am I missing somethig here.Which Direct X Version I should install in my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved Direct X9 Version is needed here which contains stream.h

Answer (score 0):

You miss the DirectShow header files.
Try add path

```
%Platform SDK Root%\Samples\Multimedia\DirectShow\BaseClasses
```

to your additional Include Directory

The reason is that DirectShow is not part of DirextX but Plantform SDK.